# Passing stuff to the view in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've done it numerous times now, but suddenly I'm unable to get it working.

This is my router

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Account.findOne(
    {
      _id: req.user._id,
    },
    function(err, acc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(acc.websites);
      res.render('reports/index', {
        title: 'Reports!',
        websites: acc.websites,
        user: req.user,
      });
    }
  );

  res.render('reports/index', {
    title: 'Report',
    user: req.user,
  });
});
```

The console log right before the res.render prints the array. `["georgiancollege.ca"]`

My view:

```
<% include ./../partials/header.ejs %>
  <h1 class="text-center">This is your report page</h1>
  <form method="post" action="/generate-report">
    <% for(let i=0; i<websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i] %>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="website" class="col-sm-2">Website <%=i+1%></label>
        <input name="website" id="website" type="text" />
      </fieldset>
      <% } %>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2">Login</button>
  </form>
  <% include ./../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

Now. When I try to get this view in the browser the error is just piling up. Here's part of the report.

```
ReferenceError: /home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/views/reports/index.ejs:4
    2|       <h1 class="text-center">This is your report page</h1>
    3|       <form method="post" action="/generate-report">
>> 4|         <% for(let i=0; i<websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i] %>
    5|           <fieldset>
    6|             <label for="website" class="col-sm-2">Website <%=i+1%></label>
    7|             <input name="website" id="website" type="text" />

websites is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:56:23)
    at returnedFn (/home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
```

And the next error

```
GET /reports 500 52.225 ms - 2919
["georgiancollege.ca"]
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: req.next is not a function
    at done (/home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:966:25)
    at tryRender (/home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:642:5)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it's irritating as hell.

Comment: You are calling `res.render()` twice in this handler. The one at the bottom will run first and doesn't pass `websites`. By the time the second one is called it's too late — you can't call it twice.

Comment: Ok I'm stupid. You're right this saved it. Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: Glad it works. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `res.render()` once. Your handler has two calls to `res.render()` so only the first one to run counts. In this case the first one to run is the one not in an async `Account.findOne()` handle and it doesn't include a `websites`element, so your template is complaining.